# Best way to write this conditional statements in scala

Tags: scala

I have two objects of same type but I want to call methods using the objects but depending upon couple of boolean values.

```
def myMethod(a: Boolean, b: Boolean, obj1: MyClass, obj2: MyClass): Future[Done] = {
    if(a) obj1.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
    if(b) obj2.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
}
```

Here the method #methodWhichReturnsFuture has return typr Future[Done]. THis is showing error since I am returning Unit here. I though of creating a 'var' and assigning it inside both method call but looks like its not a good way. This is definitely basic but I want to know what is the better way to implement this? Thanks

Comment: `if else if else`

Comment: What should happen if both `a` & `b` are `true`? Should you run both or just `obj1`? Also, what should happen if both are `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, an `if` without an `else` can only be executed for side-effect, so the resulting value of

```scala
if (a) obj1.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
```

will be discarded and the singleton value for `Unit` (`()`) will be the result.  The same will happen in the `if (b)` statement (and technically that `()` will be the result of `myMethod`, but it's the same `()` as from the `if (a)`).

You will thus need to add `else` clauses which also result in a `Future[Done]` and determine what you want the result to be if both `a` and `b` are true (furthermore, if you want both the `obj1` and `obj2` calls to be made, you will need to decide whether to execute them sequentially or in parallel) as well as if both `a` and `b` are false.

Thankfully, because `Done` is a singleton (it's basically the same as `Unit` as far as encoding "this happened", but in a way which is nicer for Java code using Akka), there's a reasonable default `Future[Done]`: `Future.successful(Done)` (which can basically be interpreted as "yeah, sure, I did it (but there was nothing to actually do)").

So if you want to do both the `obj1` and `obj2` calls simultaneously (or at least without a defined "happens-before" relationship), you could write:

```scala
val obj1Fut = if (a) obj1.methodWhichReturnsFuture() else Future.successful(Done)
val obj2Fut = if (b) obj2.methodWhichReturnsFuture() else Future.successful(Done)

// exploits eagerness of Future, won't complete until both obj1Fut and obj2Fut have completed
obj1Fut.flatMap(_ => obj2Fut)
```

If you don't want to perform the `obj2` call until after the `obj1` call:

```scala
val obj1Fut = if (a) obj1.methodWhichReturnsFuture() else Future.successful(Done)

obj1Fut.flatMap { _ =>
  if (b) obj2.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
  else Future.successful(Done)
}
```

Note that in the `Unit` returning code you presented, it's quite possible for the `obj2` future to complete before `obj1`'s future has completed.

And if you only wanted to do the `obj1` call if both `a` and `b` were true:

```scala
if (a) obj1.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
else if (b) obj2.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
else Future.successful(Done)

// or the equivalent pattern match, which might be more legible than if else if else
// (a, b) match {
//   case (true, _) => obj1.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
//   case (false, true) => obj2.methodWhichReturnsFuture()
//   case (false, false) => Future.successful(Done)
// }
```